# Hide tx_extbase_type in backend

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have created an *extbase-based plugin in Typo3 6.2*, which uses existing (non-extbase) tables from other plugins.

Although I did not yet understand this completely, it seems that a column `tx_extbase_type` is added to the existing table in order to perform the object-relational mapping.

Now, the backend shows a single-element dropdown box that holds the class name, as this cannot and should not be changed by editors, I want to hide this. How would I do that?

I have already tried to comment out the `showitem` stuff that is created in `ext_tables.php`, but this had no effect.

Comment: The field is usually used when doing inheritance in extbase. Not sure if you need it at all. You can hide it by adding `TCEFORM.<tablename>.tx_exbase_type.disabled = 1` to your Page-TS.

Comment: @Jost, please add this as the correct answer, maybe with a hint on how to disable the recordType mapping completely if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field is usually used when doing inheritance in extbase.

You can either just hide it by adding

```
TCEFORM.<tablename>.tx_extbase_type.disabled = 1
```

to your Page-TS,

**OR**

you can hide it by setting its type in TCA to `passthrough`. Not sure if this has some side effects, but in my ad hoc test it worked fine.

**OR**

you can completely remove it by removing it from:

- The file `ext_tables.sql` (run the database compare in the install tool afterwards)
- The TCA definition. You need to in these places (not sure which one the `extension_builder` uses, and not sure if you used the `extension_builder`):

  - The `type`-key of the `ctrl`-section of your table
  - The file `ext_tables.php`
  - The files in `Configuration/TCA/`
  - The files in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/*` (improbable)
  - Any files that are referenced with `dynamicConfigFile` in the `ctrl`-section of a table configuration in the TCA. Such a reference would most probably be located in `ext_tables.php`.
- The TypoScript configuration. It's located in the extbase inheritance configuration, which is usually either found

  - in the static TypoScript template of the extension (to be found under `Configuration/TypoScript` in these modern times
  - in the file `ext_conf_template.txt`
  - in  the file `ext_typoscript_setub.txt`
- Maybe some more places.

Comment: I am inheriting from an existing (non-extbase) table in an extbase extension. If I remove the field completely, will this break my extension or will it work anyway?

Comment: The `TCEFORM...` approach is working, but you have a typo in `tx_exbase_type` - that should be `tx_extbase_type`.

Comment: In case I cannot completely remove the column, is there another way to hide it (eg in the TCA definition) that is not dependent on the page configuration, ie a way to hide it "by default"?

Comment: I've added an alternative how to do that

Comment: The `passthrough` solution is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks.